# Kafka topic object into spark data frame conversion and writing into HDFS

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create kafka consumer in the spark coding ,while creating i am getting exception.My aim is i have to read from the topic and need to write into HDFS path.

```
scala> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)

scala> print(df1)
[key: binary, value: binary ... 5 more fields]
```

I am not giving any input in the topic even though it's taking these 6 values as input.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import spark.implicits._
object Read {  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("spark Oracle Kafka")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()
val df2 = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka server ip address i have given")
  .option("subscribe", "topic20190904")
  .load()

print(df1)//it is return some values 
df2.show() it's throwing exception i hope it's not dataframe.
df2.write.parquet("/user/xrrn5/abcd")// I am getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError  at rg.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala)
```

Comment: Have you considered using Kafka Connect to write the data to HDFS instead? It's specifically designed to do this, and is part of Apache Kafka.

Comment: Thanks Robin...Can I have any piece of code to do the same in kafka connect...My aim is i have to write it from kafka topic to HDFS it could be scala or kafka conncect ot Spark...

Answer (score 0):

To write data from Kafka to HDFS you don't actually need any code—you can just use Kafka Connect, which is part of Apache Kafka. Here's an example configuration:

```
{
  "name": "hdfs-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test_hdfs",
    "hdfs.url": "hdfs://localhost:9000",
    "flush.size": "3",
    "name": "hdfs-sink"
  }
}
```

[See here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html) for documentation on the connector, and [here](http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect) for a general introduction and overview of using Kafka Connect.